# How does a microservice return data to the caller when using a message broker? or a message queue?

Tags: microservices, message-queue, amqp, messagebroker

I am prettty new to microservices, and I am trying to figure out how to set a micro-service architecture in which my publisher that emits an event, can receive a response with data from the consumer within the publisher?

From what i have read about message-brokers and message-queues, it seems like it's one-way communication. The producer emits an event (or rather, sends a message) which is handled by the message broker, and then the consumer consumes that event and performs some action.

This allows for decoupled code, which is part of what im looking for, but i dont understand if the consumer is able to return any data to the caller.

Say for example I have a microservice that communicates with an external API to fetch data. I want to be able to send a message or emit an event from my front-facing server, which then calls the service that fetches data, parses the data, and then returns that data back to my servver1 (front-facing server)

Is there a way to make message brokers or queues bidirectional? Or is it only useable in one direction. I keep reading message brokers allow services to communicate with each other, but I only find examples in which data flow goes one way.

Even reading rabbitMQ documentation hasn't really made it very clear to me how i could do this

Answer (score 2):

In general, when talking about messaging, it's one-way.

When you send a letter to someone you're not opening up a mind-meld so that they telepathically communicate their response to you.

Instead, you include a return address (or some other means of contacting you).

So to map a request-response interaction when communicating with explicit messaging (e.g. via a message queue), the solution is the same: you include some directions which the recipient can/will interpret as "send a response here".  That could, for instance be, "publish a message on this queue with this correlation ID".

Your publisher then, after sending this message, subscribes to the queue it's designated and waits for a message with the expected correlation ID.

Needless to say, this is fairly elaborate: you are, in some sense, reimplementing a decent portion of a session protocol like TCP on top of a datagram protocol like IP (albeit in this case, we may have some stronger reliability guarantees than we'd get from IP).  It's worth noting that this sort of request-response interaction intrinsically couples the two parties (we can't really say "sender and receiver": each is the other's audience), so we're basically putting in some effort to decouple the two sides and then some more effort to recouple them.

With that in mind, if the actual business use case calls for a request-response interaction like this, consider implementing it with an actual request-response protocol (e.g. REST over HTTP or gRPC...) and accept that you have this coupling.

Alternatively, if you really want to pursue loose coupling, go for broke and embrace the asynchronicity at the heart of the universe (maybe that way lies true enlightenment?).  Have your publisher return success with that correlation ID as soon as its sent its message.  Meanwhile, have a different service be tracking the state of those correlation IDs and exposing a query interface (CQRS, hooray!).  Your client can then check at any time whether the thing it wanted succeeded, even if its connection to your publisher gets interrupted.

Comment: thanks for the elaborate answer, yes it seems like it is way overengineered to have a message-broker approach for something like this. I did consider trying an RPC pattern, since this is supposed to be an exercise in microservices, but it still felt like overkill. I implemented the fucntionality using REST, and that is easy mode, but im seeinghow I could make the architecture more like a microservice architecture, hence my extensive research onto this

Comment: is there a way to use rest and still have it loosely coupled?

Comment: With REST, the request-response nature implies temporal coupling: that the requester and responder have to be running at the same time (which has implications if one fails in the middle...).  The state-transfer aspect of REST also pretty much guarantees further coupling.  You can ameliorate the latter coupling with things like API versioning.

Answer (score 1):

Queues are the wrong level of abstraction for request-reply. You can build an application out of them, but it would be nontrivial to support and operate.

The solution is to use an orchestration system like [temporal.io](https://temporal.io/) or [AWS Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/). These services out of the box provide state management, asynchronous communication, and automatic recovery in case of various types of failures.

Comment: thanks! Im looking into temporal.io now, i think AWS often has a steep learning curve and i dont think it's something I can run on  a local server is it? Meanwhile, do you have any suggestions on where to start with temporal.io for this functionality? would it be workflows maybe?

Comment: If you are planning to use Go SDK start from the https://learn.temporal.io/courses/temporal_101. For other languages from documentation and samples.